# Displaying Web Pages on different mobile phones

Tags: android, iphone, windows, blackberry, browser

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to create a web page that can be displayed properly on iPhone, Android, Windows Phone, and BlackBerry (all smart phones). I use Java, and JSP.

The current web page that I have won't display properly on some phones browser (i.e. the text too small, etc). I'm thinking of checking the user agent, and then uses different CSS for different mobile phones. I can use JavaScript to check the User Agent. Is this really the best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> With the help of CSS3 and mediaqueries you can change the layout of
>   your website based on the detected screen size of the device (be it a
>   computer screen, tablet, smartphone,...).

[Here](http://www.websitedimensions.com/#)